# Read a value via ADO in an Excel file before changing it

Tags: sql-server, excel, vba

I learned a couple of weeks ago how to update an Excel file via ADO. At that time the value was already given before changing it.
Now I want to add the procedure of reading the current value in the same cell and assign the value to a variable before changing it!
The current procedure looks as follows:

```
Public Sub ChangeNum()
  Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rec As ADODB.Recordset
  Dim sqlstr As String, datasource As String
  Set con = New ADODB.Connection: Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
  datasource = "D:\DropBox\TraderShare\TraderNum.xlsx"
  Dim sconnect As String
   sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & datasource & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
  con.Open sconnect
  sqlstr = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Number] = """ & gsvDocNum & """ WHERE [ID] = """ & svNumRng & """"
  rec.Open sqlstr, con ', adOpenUnspecified, adLockUnspecified 'adLockOptimistic , adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly
  con.Close
  Set rec = Nothing: Set con = Nothing 
End Sub
```

`gsvDocNum` is a global string variable declared in the beginning of the initial startup routine, hence after reading the current value into the variable, the UPDATE one will write gsvDocNum + 1 to the file.
`svNumRng` is one of the following named ranges, `PNum`, `SNum`, `TNum` or `INum` declared in the beginning of the main routine and determined which one to look for in an earlier stage (if it’s an Purchase, SalesOrder, TradeOrder or an Invoice).

I’m not so familiar with ADO and SQL strings and I can’t find the proper syntax for SELECT for reading the current cell value and assign it to a variable before changing it with the UPDATE.

Grateful for any help!

---

OK, the background as follows: We have an administrative program I’ve written myself in Excel vba for registering purchases, orders and invoices, etc. It works pretty well for our requirements but has one issue, keeping order numbers synced between the users! We are 3 users using the program locally, each one registering orders and such, but we share the serial number file via a shared DropBox folder. I have the idea that using ADO/SQL without opening the Excel file would be faster than open, change and save the file in Excel. The reason is of course to minimize the time updating the file thus the delay before syncing to the cloud Dropfox location and to the other users computers is minimized. It’s a simple 2 column Excel file, TraderNum.xlsx:

> ID      Number
>   PNum    16000
>   SNum    16000
>   TNum    16132
>   INum    16173

I learned a couple of weeks ago how to change one of the numbers from Excel without opening the file using ADO/SQL, (see above). But I discovered that a constant update of the Excel link to a closed file for having the current number available before changing it doesn’t work as expected. Accordingly I want to use ADO/SQL also to read/assign the specific current number to a variable in the Excel procedure, before changing it with the ADO/SQL procedure above.
So somewhere between the 2 commands, rec.Open sconnect and con.Close there should be a SQL-string similar to:
sqlread = "SELECT """ & DocNumOld & """ = [Number] FROM [Sheet1$] Where [ID] = """ & svNumRng & """"
where the DocNumOld variable is assigned the current number from the chosen ID variable svNumRng.
Then the DocNumNew variable is and assigned with the DocNumOld variable incremented with 1 followed by the 
sqlUpdate sequence. It should look similar to the following:

```
Public Sub ChangeNum()
Dim con As ADODB.Connection, rec As ADODB.Recordset
Dim sqlRead as String, sqlUpdate As String, datasource As String, sconnect As String
Set con = New ADODB.Connection: Set rec = New ADODB.Recordset
datasource = "D:\DropBox\TraderShare\TraderNum.xlsx"
sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" & _
            "Data Source=" & datasource & ";" & _
            "Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES"";"
con.Open sconnect
sqlRead = "SELECT """ & DocNumOld & """ = [Number] FROM [Sheet1$] Where [ID] = """ & svNumRng & """"
sqlUpdate = "UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Number] = """ & DocNumNew & """ WHERE [ID] = """ & svNumRng & """"
rec.Open ???????, con 
????? sqlRead
DocNumNew = DocNumOld + 1
UNION
????? sqlUpdate
con.Close
Set rec = Nothing: Set con = Nothing
```

End Sub

Can you solve this, please?

Can anyone give me a solution to how to use ADO/SQL also to read/assign one specific current number to a variable in an Excel procedure, before changing it with the ADO/SQL procedure?

Comment: Surround string values with quotes "Hello Stack" or 'Hello Stack', Dates with hashes #12/2/2016#, and don't not surround numbers at all.  If  [Number]  is a numeric field then `gsvDocNum` should not be surrounded by quotes.

Comment: Try debugging the sqlstr to see output in immediate window. Please post it here so we can help with syntax. Advise also the data types of these fields.

Comment: The construction of the SELECT string is what I need help with! We can call it “sqlread”
What is the command to assign the current gsvDocNum variable with the actual number from the chosen svNumRng range before changing it with the UPDATE command?
Where/How shall I put the command, I assume before the rec.Open sqlstr, con command? Or, can I combine them?
The datasource is a simple excel number file:
ID        Number
PNum 16000
SNum 16000
TNum 16132
INum         16173

Comment: Can you post the structure with some data rows of your Excel number file? Maybe you can even show desired results of table output. You can edit your own post. Your list in comment above is not too clear. Is `ID` a number field? What are the numbers between Nums? And the claim *svNumRng is one of the following named ranges, PNum, SNum, TNum or INum* is unclear since it is checked against `ID` in `WHERE` clause.

Comment: Why not increment *Number* in place: `UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Number] = [Number] + 1 WHERE [ID] = '" & svNumRng & "'"`?

Comment: At the time when I'm running the registration application I cannot be 100% sure that the number I have from the link in Excel to the closed TradeNum-file is accurate. So either I have to open the file or.....use ADO/SQL to query for the number.

Answer (score 0):

I am concerned I don't understand your question, because the resulting comments don't make sense to me.

To restate your problem: you need to know the value of *some* cell, and be able to feed it into your code.

You can already connect to a worksheet with SQL, you already know what SELECT statements are, and you probably already know how to run them. Humor me.

```
sqlRead = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A12:F48]"
Set rec = con.Execute(sqlRead)
```

Now you have a recordset `rec` that contains the whole table. Say you wanted to put every value of the entire table in your immediate window:

```
Do While Not rec.EOF
  For i = 0 To rec.Fields.Count - 1
    Debug.Print rec.Fields(i).Name, rec.Fields(i).Value
  Next
  rec.MoveNext
Loop
```

Don't forget to close it, and I suggest using a second variable name anyway as the name of the recordset for the update statement.

```
rec.Close
```

Say you knew the cell would always be in the 3rd row, 8th column of the table you are selecting from, you might:

```
  For j = 0 to myRowNum-1 'you have set myRowNum equal to 3 earlier'
    rec.MoveNext
  Next
  myOldCellValue = rec.Fields(myColNum-1).value 'you have set myColNum to 8 earlier'
  rec.Close
```

Now, say you don't know exactly which row you will find `myOldCellValue`, but you know it will be found in the 4th column of the row that has the unique [ID] 1234, you might:

```
sqlRead = "SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$A12:F48] Where [ID] = """ & myIDNum & """" 'you have set myIDNum to 1234 earlier
Set rec = con.Execute(sqlRead)
myOldCellValue = rec.Fields(myColNum-1).value 'you have set myColNum to 4 earlier'
rec.Close
```

Say you wanted to UPDATE *every* row that had that value (I don't read that you, but for completeness), you might:

```
sqlUpdate="UPDATE [Sheet1$] SET [Number] = """ & DocNumNew & """ WHERE [DocNum] = """ & myOldCellValue & """"
```